Trying to figure out rise/fall times for different load conditions
I have a device that requires a certain rise/fall time for its input clock. It specs a .7ns rise and fall time with a 20% to 80% measurement at a Cin=6pf. I should note that the spec rise/fall time has been modified to 1.5ns per the manufacturer if you are running at a slower data rate (which we are).
Datasheet is here and the requirements are listed on p.67-68Datasheet for LS1046
The oscillator vendor list their rise/fall times of 3ns at a load of 10K||15pf with a 10% to 90% measurement.
Datasheet is here for this part and the pertinent info is on p.12Datasheet for oscillator
I am trying to figure out if this oscillator will meet the requirements of the LS1046 device.
For the different measurement scenario (20-80% vs 10-90% measurement), I did:
10% to 90% of 2.5V is .25V-2.25V and 20% to 80% of 2.5V is .5V-2V
(2.25-.25)/X = (2-.5)/1.5ns, so X=2ns, which I think means that for a measurement of 1.5ns rise/fall time at 20-80%, it will become a 2ns rise/fall time at 10-90% so the oscillator gets a .5ns relief.
For the different load scenario (6pf vs 10K||15pf), I am not sure how to calculate what the change in rise/fall time is for this case.
Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Does the oscillator vendor provide an IBIS model of the output?

I'm not putting in a lot of thought. Just the surface moments of about two minutes time...
A 40-60% duty is required. That is 3.2 ns to 4.8 ns out of an 8 ns cycle time.
If the worst case spec you have for the clock is 3 ns rise/fall times, then that's already 6 ns out of 8 ns. That won't work as there won't be enough duty cycle left over, among other reasons.
However, assuming the 6 pF input loading (I didn't read the datasheet to find that, so I'm assuming that's the clock load from your words) is as you say, then that is 2.5X better than 15 pF.
Since the capacitive load dominates everything that matters (the parallel 10 k is irrelevant at these speeds), you should see an actual 2.5X improvement in rise/fall from the clock into that 6 pF input load.
Worst case, that may still not be quite enough of an improvement. But worst case isn't typical, either. So close enough that I'd consider the idea.
It looks to me as though you have expended good effort, so far. And if you'd found another option, you probably wouldn't be here asking about this one. So if I'm right that you can't find better options, then I'd work with field engineers from both companies and add an early research investigation step into the project lab notebook to be performed to validate the situation over various ambient temperatures and parts, as many combinations as I could afford.
If things work out well enough to gain solid confidence and the field engineers provide some level of confidence about their processes, testing, and guarantees and future of their devices, then I might use them. However, I'd also be logging down every experiment performed and its results, my summary of every field engineer conversation with date and time and person, and log my thinking and reasoning for concluding that using these parts for the product is justified.
Then I'd set aside this problem and move on to the next one.
